# Obtaining m/n probability with fair coin

Tags: probability

If I have fair coin, is there any way to obtain $\frac{m}{n}$ probability with it? Is there any algorithm or sequence of actions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please add detail and context. For example, what ideas do you have about solving the problem? Otherwise the question is likely to be downvoted or closed. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Hint: Flip it $k$ times where $2^k  \geq n$. How do you get a probability of $m/n$ from there?

Comment: @CalvinLin so, m/n should be fraction 1/2^t ?

Comment: Must you use all $2^t$ events to create the probability space? Can you "forget" / ignore some of these events?